# Simultaneity in relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, relativity

Two cars, one from X axis and another from Y axis are travelling near the speed of light towards the origin. They do avoid collision in one frame of reference but collides in the lab frame of reference. How is it possible for both to happen? 
I've understood some problems in simultaneity but this one is confusing me.

Comment: It is not possible for both to happen: either the cars collide (their world-lines intersect at some event), or they don't (their world-lines do not intersect).  If you think otherwise you probably need to provide more information so we can see where you are confused.

Comment: What doees it mean to collide in a frame of reference?

Comment: The question goes like this... both cars travel with the speed c/5 towards each other. One of them travel along X axis and another one along Y axis. Is there a frame of reference in which they avoid collision?

Comment: If there is a frame in which they do avoid collision then what about the frames in which they collide. How can both be true?

Comment: there answer is no, there is no such frame

Comment: @Vivekkarunakaran They collide in all frames. Or don't collide in any frame. If you consider Lorentz transformation properly you will see that everything is consistent. The direct analogy is - if two lines do (not) intersect this fact will not change if you rotate everything

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 1):

If they collide in the lab's frame of reference, theirs 4-vector of position are the same for that frame for that event. So, the difference between the 4-vectors is zero.

Any Lorentz transformation of a zero vector results in a zero vector. So they collide in any other frame.